# Какой метод лучше использовать в php

Tags: php, методы

Всем привет! В примерах учебника по `php` методы как и члены класса прописываются закрытыми, и там вроде всё норм, при этом когда я прописываю методы закрытыми, браузер выдаёт ошибки с названием этих методов. А когда методы открытые всё вроде без ошибок.
Вот у меня и возник вопрос, правильно ли прописывать методы закрытыми?

Пример:

```
class uns
    {
    private $arr=array();

    public function __get($index)
    {
        return $this->arr[$index];
    }
    public function __set($index, $value)
    {
        $this->arr[$index]=$value;
    }
    public function __isset($index)
    {
        return isset($this->arr[$index]);
    }
    public function __unset($index)
    {
        unset($this->arr[$index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Прочитайте много раз до достижения понимания:

- [Модификаторы доступа в PHP](http://myrusakov.ru/modifikatory-dostupa-php.html)
- [Область видимости](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дополню предыдущего оратора) Публичные методы можно вызывать снаружи класса, это внешний интерфейс, который можно использовать где угодно. Приватные методы могут использоваться только самим классом внутри его же методов, их нигде не должно быть видно и никому не надо показывать.

Comment: Вот браузер их и не видит.

Comment: Браузер не должен видеть PHP вообще, т.к. скрипты PHP выполняются на сервере. Если какие-то методы твоего класса вызываются где-то кроме самого класса, эти методы должны быть public. Иначе, их никто не сможет использовать.

Comment: Разумеется. Зарапортовался. Не видит эти методы, конечно же, php. Браузер только получает сообщения об ошибках.

Answer (score 1):

Смотря для чего. Есть три модификатора для свойства или метода класса: public(открытый), private(закрытый), protected(защищенный). private и protected для обращения к свойствам или методам внутри класса, protected можно также наследовать

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php